# Eclipse: Include dependencies of other project in WAR

Tags: java, eclipse, war

In Eclipse, I have two projects. 
One is a Web-Project which should be exported as a WAR-File.
The second one is a Java-project which exists only to bundle several dependency-jars. (Since it's a lot of jars and they don't exist in maven repo, having a project for them seemed the easiest solution to bundle them together)

Now the Web-Project depends on having the JARs from the dependency-project in WEB-INF/lib-Folder. I already performed the following steps:

- Include JARs in Build-Path of Dependency-Project
- Export all the JARs from Dependency-Project (using Order and Export tab)
- Include Dependency-Project in Web-Projects Build-Path
- Add Dependency-Project to Deployment Assembly of Web-Project using Deploy Path `WEB-INF/lib/dependencies.jar` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3086309/7677308))

But even though the Dependency-Project is included in Deployment Assembly, it is not exported in the WAR-File. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the jars as maven dependencies by phantasy groupid, phantasy artifactid and phantasy version.

Comment: I already thought about that, but it's about 50 JARs, so this would be a lot of work. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: You could create a script to work for all the 50 jars. Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes, but when I use Maven, the jars should be deployed to a Nexus repository

Comment: @SilverNak This may help: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html